# Identify a childrens/YA book where a poltergeist gets stuck in a computer game and shipped back to ireland

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

When I was in elementary school I read a book where in a ghoul somehow got to the local setting. I want to say it was in the US, but that could just be my eagle-centric mindset. The poltergeist followed a couple of children around, a brother and sister. The poltergeist was moving things in relatively non-harmful ways (I remember a scene involving a roller desk?), but the parents brought in a paranormal specialist who blamed it on the girls latent psychic abilities. The brother was a computer aficionado, and at one time upon playing his game an entity appeared near the games character that was a representation of this poltergeist. Eventually, they put it on a disk and ship it back to either Scotland or Ireland. At one point the children worked with a friend of family who spoke Gaelic to help them understand the poltergeist, but I don't remember wherein the story this occurred.

Does anyone know this story and the name of the bookl?

Edit -- To clarify I was in elementary school from '96 - 2000, and it was in English.

Comment: This was in English? Also, can you clarify when you were in elementary school?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Susan Cooper's 1993 *[The Boggart](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/858349.The_Boggart)*

[image: The Boggart - Hardcover book cover (1993)]

> "Centuries old and housands of miles from home". When Emily and Jess Volnik's family inherits a remote, crumbling Scottish castle, they also inherit the Boggart - an invisible, mischievous spirit who's been playing tricks on residents of Castle Keep for generations. Then the Boggart is trapped in a rolltop desk and inadvertently shipped to the Volniks' home in Toronto, where nothing will ever be the same - for the Volniks or the Boggart.
>
> In a world that doesn't believe in magic, the Boggart's pranks wreak havoc. And even the newfound joys of peanut butter and pizza and fudge sauce eventually wear thin for the Boggart. He wants to go home - but his only hope lies in a risky and daring blend of modern technology and ancient magic.

The reviews discuss how they get him back home by putting him on a computer disk for a video game.

> Besides the strong writing and engaging story, I was struck by the boggart as a sympathetic character, especially when he is finally able to tell them he wants to go home. The use of a computer game was clever.

Comment: This is it, but It was definitely before 2005. Quick googling suggests it was published originally in '93.

Comment: Fixed. I was initially looking at a republished version.

Comment: First result for me when searching for *book poltergeist "computer game" ireland*. Doing it without Ireland brings up a lot of mentions of the (rather abysmal) TRS-80 game.

Comment: My google-fu is decidedly not impressive.

Comment: @Sidney: Eh, the choice of keywords can have a huge difference in what shows up. :)